# Bug using -ms-viewport with Windows Phone and Microsoft Edge?

Tags: css, windows-phone-8, viewport

After a lot of effort trying to render my site properly on Windows Phone, I found a solution using **@-ms-viewport()**. It worked fine until I tested on Microsoft Edge. It renders the exact same way as Windows Phone, so it turns "super-sized".

You can check for yourself, live: http://yordles.com or [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/9ap77g)

There's a way a can target windows phone only or microsoft edge only?

Thank you!